# scrolling issue in hybrid application - which contains iframe inside it

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi have one hybrid app.

its working fine in all device except samsung s3 and s4.

scrolling is not smooth in both two device.

My hybrid application contains a iframe inside it...
I tried to goolge it but no solution so far.

anyone every face this issue to please help me out for the same

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Dojo by any chance? I have seen some defects in dojo based on these devices and transitions.

Comment: no its simple jquery mobile